# How to get last message send by user. My code gives me error "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using this code to get last message with contact list. When execute it gives me an error "explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given"

```
$lastmsgdIds = Message::select(\DB::raw('`text` as usermessage, `from_user_id` as fromuser,`to_user_id` as touser'))->get();


    $contacts3 = $contacts3->map(function ($contacts3) use ($lastmsgdIds) {
        $me = Auth::user()->id;
        $userID = $contacts3->id;
        $lastmessage = $lastmsgdIds
            ->where(function ($query) use ($userID, $me) {
                $query->where('fromuser', $userID)->where('touser', $me);
            })->oRwhere(function ($query) use ($userID, $me) {
                $query->where('fromuser', $me)->where('touser', $userID);
            })->first();

        $contacts3->lastmsg =  $lastmessage->usermessage;

        return $contacts3;
    });
```

Comment: change `oRwhere` to `orWhere`

Comment: no its not working `oRwhere` and `orWhere` same

Comment: Can you say what you exactly wants ?

Comment: I have contact table and message table. i want to get last message send by contact list user to me

Comment: where did you use `explode()`?

Comment: in error message

Comment: [link](https://ibb.co/WvVGWch)